# How to filter sessions based on their length in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame in pandas, which consists of ~35 million rows and the average sequence length is around 22:

```
session     id               servertime
      1   3085  2018-10-09 13:20:25.096
      1   3671  2018-10-21 08:19:39.078
      1   2015  2018-10-23 21:22:27.647
      7   4066  2018-10-29 00:04:16.707
      7   4991  2018-10-30 11:00:57.918
      7   4495  2018-10-31 04:50:56.864
      7   5131  2018-11-04 10:49:03.044
      7   4982  2018-11-04 12:02:03.738
      7   4495  2018-11-04 12:43:53.595
      7   3906  2018-11-05 16:55:17.891
      7   8743  2018-11-06 16:55:17.891
      7   6541  2018-11-07 16:55:17.891
      7   3447  2018-11-08 16:55:17.891
      7   6541  2018-11-08 18:55:17.891
      7   1234  2018-11-09 16:55:17.891
     20  10256  2018-08-28 11:09:35.902
     20  11220  2018-09-09 06:49:48.44
     20   5237  2018-09-13 12:01:09.677
     20   5547  2018-09-13 12:02:34.762
     20   6454  2018-09-13 12:07:40.061
```

I want to filter out the "oldest" values from a sequence, when the length of the sequence is above 10. 
Meaning, in the upper DataFrame the length of sequence 7 is 12. Therefore, i want to filter out the two first rows in that sequence.

The expected output should therefore be the following:

```
session     id               servertime
      1   3085  2018-10-09 13:20:25.096
      1   3671  2018-10-21 08:19:39.078
      1   2015  2018-10-23 21:22:27.647
      7   4495  2018-10-31 04:50:56.864
      7   5131  2018-11-04 10:49:03.044
      7   4982  2018-11-04 12:02:03.738
      7   4495  2018-11-04 12:43:53.595
      7   3906  2018-11-05 16:55:17.891
      7   8743  2018-11-06 16:55:17.891
      7   6541  2018-11-07 16:55:17.891
      7   3447  2018-11-08 16:55:17.891
      7   6541  2018-11-08 18:55:17.891
      7   1234  2018-11-09 16:55:17.891
     20  10256  2018-08-28 11:09:35.902
     20  11220  2018-09-09 06:49:48.44
     20   5237  2018-09-13 12:01:09.677
     20   5547  2018-09-13 12:02:34.762
     20   6454  2018-09-13 12:07:40.061
```

How do I do that the most efficient way?

Thank you beforehand.

/Mathias

Comment: Sorry, what is expected output? Can you add to question?

Comment: Has now been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns and then use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df['servertime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['servertime'])

df1 = (df.sort_values(['session','servertime'])
         .groupby('session', sort=False)
         .tail(10))
print (df1)
    session     id              servertime
0         1   3085 2018-10-09 13:20:25.096
1         1   3671 2018-10-21 08:19:39.078
2         1   2015 2018-10-23 21:22:27.647
5         7   4495 2018-10-31 04:50:56.864
6         7   5131 2018-11-04 10:49:03.044
7         7   4982 2018-11-04 12:02:03.738
8         7   4495 2018-11-04 12:43:53.595
9         7   3906 2018-11-05 16:55:17.891
10        7   8743 2018-11-06 16:55:17.891
11        7   6541 2018-11-07 16:55:17.891
12        7   3447 2018-11-08 16:55:17.891
13        7   6541 2018-11-08 18:55:17.891
14        7   1234 2018-11-09 16:55:17.891
15       20  10256 2018-08-28 11:09:35.902
16       20  11220 2018-09-09 06:49:48.440
17       20   5237 2018-09-13 12:01:09.677
18       20   5547 2018-09-13 12:02:34.762
19       20   6454 2018-09-13 12:07:40.061
```

Comment: But this one sorts out all sequences above a length of 10, right?
I dont want that, but just the oldest of the values sorted out (see expected output in the question)

Comment: @MathiasByskov - yes, sorry, first I dont understand your question. Please check edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd sort your dataframe by date so those are in order. Then just keep the last 10 rows of each groupby session.

```
# sort your dataframe by servertime
df = df.sort(['servertime'], ascending=[True])

# get groups by the session, and get last 10 rows
df.groupby('session').tail(10).reset_index(drop=True)
```